# How to access PHP variable from other file?

Tags: php, variables

So I want to access a variable (`$username`) from file `quickprotect.login.php` and print it in file `index.php`. File `login.ini.php` contains username configuration and `quickprotect.login.php` contains:

```
<?php
$root = dirname(__FILE__);

class quickprotect {
    private $ini_file_location = "login.ini.php";
    private static $tries;
    public static $errormsg;

    public $settings;

    public function __construct() {
        session_start();
        $this->ini_file_location = $GLOBALS[root] . "/" . $this->ini_file_location;
        $this->settings = @parse_ini_file($this->ini_file_location);
        if (!$this->settings) {
            die("Failed to load the INI file located at: $this->ini_file_location.");
        }
    }

    public function login($username, $password) {

        // Performs login by initializing $_SESSION vars
        // Returns true or false, plus $_SESSION message on success/failiure
        // Contains brute force protection

        if (!isset($_SESSION['tries'])) $_SESSION['tries'] = 1;
        if ($_SESSION['tries'] <= intval($this->settings[MAX_TRIES]) || $this->settings[ALLOW_UNLIMITED_TRIES] == true) {
            //Try to prevent brute forcing
            if (sha1(trim($password)) == trim($this->settings[ADMIN_PW]) && $username === $this->settings[USERNAME]) {
                // other codes
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And when I use:

```
include 'quickprotect.login.php';
echo "User: $username";
```

It gives:

```
User:
```

Can anyone advise? Thx in advance :)

Update: Solved it by:

```
include '../quickprotect.class.php'
$qp = new quickprotect();
$un=   $qp->settings['USERNAME']; 
mail("mail@domain.com","Report","=== Username: $un");
```

Comment: I don't see `$username` defined anywhere. At a guess, you want `$qp = new quickprotect(); echo 'User: ', $qp->settings['USERNAME'];`

Comment: You should also learn to quote your array indices, ie `$this->settings['ADMIN_PW']`, **not** `$this->settings[ADMIN_PW]`. I'd also avoid using `$GLOBALS`. Instead, just use `__DIR__ . '/' . $this->ini_file_location`

Comment: How can I use it inside php mail()?

Comment: quickprotect.login.php does not contain $username. So your question makes no sense.

Comment: @Phil, it worked. Pls make it an answer so that i can accept :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use php $_POST if you  are using form on other page

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you wrote this ?

```
echo "User: $username";
```

Because it should be

```
echo "User: ".$username;
```

To get the actual value of the variable.